# Is it possible to use battery chargers as power supply?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I have a Foxsur 12V 7A max battery charger and I wanted to use it as a power supply. However, when I hooked it up, it did not power it as it did not recognise it as a battery. Is there a way to allow the battery charger to still output energy?

Comment: That will depend on the device and you've told us very little about that. A make, model and link to the user manual would seem to be a reasonable minimum requirement.

Comment: Generally speaking, battery chargers are meant to charge batteries, and so these may try to detect that there is a valid battery connected before starting to output power, and thus they may perform poorly as power supplies even if you simulate a battery.

Comment: Some yes, others no. You need to test your particular one to tell.

Comment: You can find a nice, used lab power supply on eBay for surprisingly little. Always use the correct tools for the job.